# linking html from another html file?

Tags: html

I know this may be a stupid question, im newer to this.
My menu bar takes over 1,000 lines in my html file. My client wants his `index.html` file organized so he can edit himself if needed.
I want to know if i can put my html for my menu in another files for instance in a file called : menu.html
and link in my `index.html` file by

`<link href="../files/menu.html " type="text/html">`

or in any other way that would work?

Comment: @SLaks Sorry im new to this im only 16 im teaching myself all this. lol how do i do that? could you point me in the direction of a webpage that would explain.

Comment: have you tried for example a piece of dirty php code? something like `<?php include("../files/menu.html"); ?>`? it is no beautiful solution, but might work for you... Remember your index page has to be a php file then...

Comment: havent tried but thanks for the info i will give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

if you are using any programming language, use its code. For example, if you are using php 
use

```
include_once('../files/menu.html');
```